# How to create an additional domain controller using Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm currently running Windows Server 2008 R2, can anyone tell me how I can replicate the active directory to another server which has been installed using Server Core install.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to set up an additional domain controller using a Server Core edition of Windows Server 2008 R2, you need to add the Active Directory Domain Services role to the server and then run `dcpromo.exe` in order to promote it to a DC in the existing domain. All of this, or course, has to be done from the command line, being it a Server Core setup.

This article should help getting you started:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772154(WS.10).aspx

In order to add the Domain Controller role to the server, you can run these PowerShell commands:

```
Import-Module Servermanager
Add-WindowsFeature ADDS-Domain-Controller
```

In order to promote the server to DC in an existing domain, you can run a command similar to this one:

```
dcpromo.exe /unattend /InstallDns:yes /ConfirmGC:yes /replicaOrNewDomain:replica /replicaDomainDNSName:<YOUR DOMAIN NAME> /safeModeAdminPassword:<DSRM Password>
```

Where `<YOUR DOMAIN NAME>` is the FQDN of your Active Directory domain and `<DSRM Password>` is the password to set for Directory Services Restore Mode on the new DC.

The command should of course be run by an user with Domain Admin rights.

Comment: This covers the answer more clearly, as with Server Core you must use the CMD line and an answer file for the DCpromo.

Comment: The answer file is not needed, DCPROMO can take command-line parameters in Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that bonus.  Nice clarification!

Answer (score 8):

You promote it to a domain controller in the same domain using `Dcpromo.exe` the same way you would promote any other DC. The replication happens automatically.